# One hour added when converting date to unix timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

When converting a date to unix timestamp and formatting it, one hour is being added. What I am doing wrong?

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> import datetime

>>> date_str = "2014-12-09T19:00:00+1100"
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str)
>>> unix = int(date.strftime('%s'))

>>> date_str
'2014-12-09T19:00:00+1100'

>>> date
2014-12-09 19:00:00+11:00

>>> print(unix)
1418115600

>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
2014-12-09 20:00:00
```

The hour has been changed from 19:00 to 20:00. I am suspecting this has something to do with time zone. But I have no clue what exactly is going wrong.

I used [Epoch calculator](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to verify the unix timestamp. It seems that the one hour is being added in the process of convert **date** variable to unix timestamp. (date = dateutil.parser.parse(date_str))

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')` ?

Comment: I get '2014-12-09 20:00:00 '. It seems that timezone offset is missing. @hobbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a Unix timestamp from a datetime object by doing:

```
import pytz

timestamp = int((datetime_obj - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds())
```

This requires the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) library. We're using [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) so this solution is Python 2.7+.

In your case that gives you the timestamp 1418112000 which matches the original datetime.

Comment: This actually works. But I am just wondering if date.strftime('%s') gives you the seconds from unix epoch, it should give you exactly the same value that you are obtaining with the calculation. Why the one hour different? @Simeon Visser

Comment: @Dane: I'm not sure, I don't see `%s` documented so I can't tell whether it behaves as it should. I don't think you should be using `%s`.

Comment: See the docs; it's converted to your machine's local date and time, unless you specify the timezone as an argument.